# Iphone: Highlight row when added

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm developing an application where the user adds new rows to an existing table. When a new row is added, i want to highlight it and make the view focus on the row if the table is scrollable.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I`m still kinda new to iphone and objective-c so any help is highly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the NSIndexPath of the row you just added, calling selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: on your table should do the trick:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                            animated:YES 
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

Comment: ah, nice.. I know the index, so I will test this asap :)